# Crash "libnvblit.so Blit" from Android 11 NVIDIA darcy devices

Tags: android

Google play reports the following crash from Android 11 NVIDIA darcy devices:

```
[libnvblit.so] Blit
SIGSEGV
backtrace:
  #00  pc 0x00000000000059b8  /vendor/lib64/libnvblit.so (Blit+288)
  #01  pc 0x00000000000052a8  /vendor/lib64/libnvblit.so (NvBlit+240)
  #02  pc 0x000000000000d648  /vendor/lib64/hw/gralloc.tegra.so (NvGr2dBlit+472)
  #03  pc 0x000000000000ac60  /vendor/lib64/hw/gralloc.tegra.so (NvGrUnlockAsync+204)
  #04  pc 0x00000000000106e0  /vendor/lib64/hw/gralloc.tegra.so (NvGr1Unlock+92)
  #05  pc 0x0000000000003870  /vendor/lib64/hw/android.hardware.graphics.mapper@2.0-impl.so (android::hardware::graphics::mapper::V2_0::passthrough::detail::Gralloc1HalImpl<android::hardware::graphics::mapper::V2_0::hal::MapperHal>::unlock(native_handle const*, android::base::unique_fd_impl<android::base::DefaultCloser>*)+56)
  #06  pc 0x0000000000004e48  /vendor/lib64/hw/android.hardware.graphics.mapper@2.0-impl.so (android::hardware::graphics::mapper::V2_0::hal::detail::MapperImpl<android::hardware::graphics::mapper::V2_0::IMapper, android::hardware::graphics::mapper::V2_0::hal::MapperHal>::unlock(void*, std::__1::function<void (android::hardware::graphics::mapper::V2_0::Error, android::hardware::hidl_handle const&)>)+88)
  #07  pc 0x0000000000010a2c  /system/lib64/android.hardware.graphics.mapper@2.0.so (android::hardware::graphics::mapper::V2_0::BsMapper::unlock(void*, std::__1::function<void (android::hardware::graphics::mapper::V2_0::Error, android::hardware::hidl_handle const&)>)+132)
  #08  pc 0x000000000002b7f8  /system/lib64/libui.so (android::Gralloc2Mapper::unlock(native_handle const*) const+108)
  #09  pc 0x00000000000393f0  /system/lib64/libui.so (android::GraphicBufferMapper::unlock(native_handle const*)+44)
  #10  pc 0x0000000000168700  /system/lib64/libstagefright.so (android::SoftwareRenderer::render(void const*, unsigned long, long, long, unsigned long, android::sp<android::AMessage> const&)+920)
  #11  pc 0x000000000011896c  /system/lib64/libstagefright.so (android::MediaCodec::onReleaseOutputBuffer(android::sp<android::AMessage> const&)+880)
  #12  pc 0x000000000010b100  /system/lib64/libstagefright.so (android::MediaCodec::onMessageReceived(android::sp<android::AMessage> const&)+4812)
  #13  pc 0x0000000000017814  /system/lib64/libstagefright_foundation.so (android::AHandler::deliverMessage(android::sp<android::AMessage> const&)+84)
  #14  pc 0x000000000001d9cc  /system/lib64/libstagefright_foundation.so (android::AMessage::deliver()+188)
  #15  pc 0x0000000000018b48  /system/lib64/libstagefright_foundation.so (android::ALooper::loop()+572)
  #16  pc 0x0000000000015598  /system/lib64/libutils.so (android::Thread::_threadLoop(void*)+460)
  #17  pc 0x00000000000a0c14  /system/lib64/libandroid_runtime.so (android::AndroidRuntime::javaThreadShell(void*)+144)
  #18  pc 0x0000000000014d94  /system/lib64/libutils.so (thread_data_t::trampoline(thread_data_t const*)+412)
  #19  pc 0x00000000000afd4c  /apex/com.android.runtime/lib64/bionic/libc.so (__pthread_start(void*)+64)
  #20  pc 0x0000000000050288  /apex/com.android.runtime/lib64/bionic/libc.so (__start_thread+64)
```

It happens multiple times a day on some devices. Could anyone shed some light on the possible causes of this crash to allow me to figure out a remedy?